# Passing CMD Results to Variable in a Batch File

Tags: variables, scripting, batch-file

I am trying to install an application and a group of services using PSTools, but I want to take into account that the computer I am trying to connect to may be turned off or on a different network, which is not reachable from the internal network.

Basically if the machine is not able to be accessed through the admin share, this is the message that I am getting:

> Couldn't access *MachineName*:
>   The network path was not found.
>   Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on *MachineName*.

This is the syntax I am using to try to capture the "Error Message" and then report back that if installation was successful or not (depending on if it can contact the machine)

```
@echo off
set /p name=What is the machine name?: 
psexec.exe \\%name% -u *useraccount* -p *password* \\ServerName\installation.bat
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('COMMAND ^| FIND "Couldn't access"') DO SET Error=%%A
If "%Error%"=="Couldn't access" 
ECHO Installation Failed.
Else
ECHO Installtion complete.  
Pause
exit
```

Currently it hangs right at the point it's defining the Error Variable.  Can't quite figure out what I am going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'COMMAND ^| FIND "Couldn't access"'` opens a command shell, which is why it hangs. It will not proceed until that shell is exited.

You will need to look at redirecting the error messages to another file. `2>Errors.txt` on the psexec line will give you a file to search in the next line.

this will make the batch file look something like this:

```
@echo off
set /p name=What is the machine name?: 
psexec.exe \\\%name% ... \\\ServerName\installation.bat 1>Error.txt 2>&1 
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('FIND /i error.txt "Couldn't Access"') do SET Error=%%A
If not x%ERROR:Couldn=%==x%ERROR% (
ECHO Installation Failed.
) Else (
ECHO Installtion complete.  
)
Pause
exit
```

(Also, notice the use of brackets to make a multi line IF)
the check for if will see if `Couldn` is part of the string, as a direct comparison will not work, as you would have to check against the whole string including the machine name

Comment: ok it's writing to the file, but as soon as it hits `for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (Error.txt) do SET Error=%%A` it just closes.

This is my code in it's entirety:

`:loop
cls
set /p name=What is the machine name?: 
psexec.exe \\%name% -u username -p password \\ServerName\path\file.bat 1>Error.txt 2>&1
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (Error.txt) do SET Error=%%A
If %Error% == "The handle is invalid."
then 
Echo Installation Failed.
Else
ECHO Installation Success.
Pause
goto loop`

Comment: once you have the `%ERROR%` variable set, you should be able to check it, as in your example batch file - edited answer

Comment: It is assigning the last line of the error.txt as the variable: `Connecting to computername...`. I want it to assign the value of "The handle is invalid" if that setence exists in error.txt.

Comment: changed for /f to run the find command on the error. fixed the comparison (hopefully)

Comment: assuming your test.txt is my error.txt, it is still failing.  It is closing at the variable assignment.

Comment: Got it.... `for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('FIND /i error.txt "The handle is invalid."') do SET Error=%%A If "%ERROR%"=="The handle is invalid." ( ECHO Installation Failed. ) Else ( ECHO Installtion Complete. ) Pause goto loop`

Thanks for your help!